# How to unit test with a recursive object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have an object that takes in a parameter of the same type in the constructor:

```
public class Person {
    private Person theParent;
    private string theName;
    public Person(string aName, Person aParent)
    {
        if(aParent == null)
        {
            thrown new ArgumentNullException("aParent");
        }
        theParent = aParent;
        theName = aName;
    }
}
```

In my unit test I have to create a new `Person` object but the constructor requires another `Person` object to be passed in.  I overcome this problem in my application by getting the `Person` object to pass in from the database (using NHibernate and all its magic)*.  I don't want to tie database access into this test as it is not testing any database functionality.  Should I just mock the parent object (I'm using Rhino Mocks in some of my other tests) or is there a better way to approach this?

*There is guaranteed to always be one record in the databse that I can retrieve to make the parent object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that at some point you are expected to reach a top node? What is the correct value for `aParent` then?

My guess would be `null`, and that would mean this `Person` is the very first in it's line (whatever that means for your application, perhaps [Adam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_and_Eve) or something?).

Comment: Yes, there is a top node which is the node that the application retrieves from the database during normal use.  All other nodes require that a parent is supplied.  Null is not an allowed parent for integrity reasons.

Comment: I assume the `Person` class is more advanced than your code shows, but is that top node's state integral to your test(s)? If not, you will most likely get good results with a simple mock object. 

If the actual object in the DB however *is* integral to the test, this is most likely an integration test and you should separate it from your unit tests and just go ahead and read from the DB.

Comment: Ah, after your edit I would suggest a mock object for a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You may test side effects of the recursive function call, e.g. use counter field variable to check number of calls, store call parameter at some kind of container where Unit Test can check them etc. Of course, you will remove all these things in the release build.